# How can I make this function with substr work when rk is null or ""

Tags: c#

I have the following function in C#:

```
    public string getRowKey(string topic, string rk)
    {
        return string.Join("", from s in topic.Split('.')
                               select s.PadLeft(2, '0')).PadRight(4, '0') +
                    rk.Substring(4);
    }
```

I have a problem because if rk is null or equal to "" then the function is failing. Can someone explain how I can fix this. I am getting an error about index values. Note that if rk is null or "" then I just don't want that last part with rk.Substring(4) added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple use of ternary operator `?:` and function `string.IsNullOrEmpty(string)` would suffice

```
public string getRowKey(string topic, string rk)
{
    return string.Join("", from s in topic.Split('.')
                           select s.PadLeft(2, '0')).PadRight(4, '0') +
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(rk) ? "": rk.Substring(4);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
 public string getRowKey(string topic, string rk)     {
    return string.Join("", from s in topic.Split('.')
        select s.PadLeft(2, '0')).PadRight(4, '0') +                     
   string.IsNullOrEmpty(rk)?"":rk.Substring(4);     
}
```

Note that you will also need to check the size of rk is greater than four.

Comment: Greater than 4... And I'd go with string.Empty instead of ""

Answer (score 1):

```
public string getRowKey(string topic, string rk)
{
    return string.Join("", from s in topic.Split('.')
                           select s.PadLeft(2, '0')).PadRight(4, '0') +
                (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rk) ? "" : rk.Substring(4));
}
```